# Is it possible to enter values in a row/column based on the total sum of the row AND column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Example:

I know the sum of Row 1 should be 300. There are 5 columns. Each column must total 60 each. Easy, division.

What if I have Rows 1-35 with differently known totals (i.e. Row 1 is 300, Row 2 is 107, Row 3 is 500) AND the same 5 columns that must total 300 each in Row 36?

Is there a formula or VBA script that can calculate this information for me?

Comment: I need more information. Is this some kind of sudoku-like puzzle? Perhaps you could provide some sample data.

Comment: That is the sample data. Also, yes, like Sudoku almost.

Comment: Use Solver Addin